# Command CompileXIB failed with a nonzero exit code error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

[image]

My project runs good in Xcode 11. But when I build it in Xcode 12 gets the above error. I have been struggling for a while and no answers worked for me.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Had you been able to find any solution for your problem. If yes then please share here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an old question, but I was struggling with such issue for a few hours today and in my case it was related to the version of the tools that is declared in xib's document structure. To fix it, take a `toolsVersion` value from any newly created xib file (either in your current project, or a new one), then open failing xib with any code editor (or view its source in Xcode) and replace `toolsVersion` with the acquired one.
In my case the old version was 18122 and the valid one is 20034.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I ran into this the other day and wasn't really finding any direct solutions.

What appears to have worked for me was correcting the "builds for" value in Interface Builder.  The xib file was from a project that supports a level of iOS several versions later than the project I was copying it into, and there were elements within the interface (like stack views) that weren't supported in the older OS.  Once I changed the "builds for" value to an OS version that *does* support those UI elements, the problem went away (note that this subsequently required me setting up version checks in and around the files associated with the xib to only allow access if the user's device meets the minimum "builds for" value set on the xib).

If you're unsure where the "builds for" picker is:

In Xcode, select the xib file, and select the File Inspector within the Inspector pane (pane on the right hand side).  Set the builds for value to an OS that supports all elements used within the xib, and see if that clears up the error.

[image]